# Сериализация в XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, serializable

Делаю сериализацию по [примеру](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/thread_and_files/level4/4_1.php)

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
[Serializable]
public class UserPrefs
{
    public string WindowColor;
    public int FontSize;
}
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        UserPrefs userData = new UserPrefs();
        userData.WindowColor = "Yellow";
        userData.FontSize = 50;           
        BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
        // Сохранить объект в локальном файле.
        using (Stream fStream = new FileStream("user.xml",
           FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            binFormat.Serialize(fStream, userData);
        }
    }
}
```

Файл создается но как xml файл он не открывается пишет не удается отобразить страницу XML. Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Comment: заголовок файла содержит `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` ? приложите xml к вопросу

Comment: яяяя          :RDS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   
RDS.UserPrefs   WindowColorFontSize       Yellow2

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите получить? Если XML то вам нужен другой сериализатор.

Comment: дайте пример xml сериализации

Comment: Даю: http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.4.php Но неужели сложно вбить в поиск запрос самостоятельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы нашли — это бинарная сериализация, а не сериализация в XML.

Надо так:

```
UserPrefs userData = new UserPrefs();
userData.WindowColor = "Yellow";
userData.FontSize = 50;

//var xml = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData);
XmlSerializer seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserPrefs));
// тут вам скорее всего нужен другой тип stream'с
using (var s = new MemoryStream())
{
    seri.Serialize(s, userData);
    // всё, сериализация окончена
    // перегоним в строку для контроля
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var text = new StreamReader(s).ReadToEnd();
}
```

В переменной `text` будет следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<UserPrefs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <WindowColor>Yellow</WindowColor>
  <FontSize>50</FontSize>
</UserPrefs>
```

Если вам нужно записать в файл, вместо `MemoryStream`'а берите сразу `FileStream` и т. д.

```
using (var s = File.Create(@"user.xml"))
{
    seri.Serialize(s, userData);
}
```

Comment: А почему MemoryStream, а не StringWriter?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Я имел в виду любой `Stream`. Скорее всего ТС'у нужен какой-нибудь `FileStream`.

Comment: Я везде до сих пор писал через MemoryStream. Думаю через StringWriter возможно лучше...

Comment: @nick_n_a: MemoryStream тут только для примера, скорее всего ТС'у нужен FileStream или NetworkStream.